# How can I prevent the fireplace smell when the A/C is on?

Tags: hvac, fireplace, smell

I get the ashy fireplace smell in the family room when the A/C is running.  I haven't had a fire burning in months.

I checked out [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/21549/10029), but it targets a recent fire and a cold air return.

It would seem that I'm getting negative pressure in the house when the A/C is running, being equalized through the fireplace.  I have a Buck Stove insert that was there when we bought the house.  Consequently, I don't have the standard flue closure mechanism.  It's more of a stepped closure to control airflow while the stove is burning.

Is there anything I can do to prevent the negative pressure that comes with running the A/C?

Comment: Are you sure it's negative pressure?  A/C doesn't cause negative pressure like exhaust fans or dryers do.  Could it just be the cold air return in that room is 'over zealous' ?  You might experiment by blocking the nearest return off.

Comment: @HerrBag, The thing is, the smell is really only in that room, so I don't think the actual ventilation system is actually involved.  At least, that's why I surmised it was a pressure thing.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be a Heat Recovery Ventilator(HRV) that exchanges interior air for outside, which will relieve negative pressure.

Another would be a dampered (and screened) make-up air that connects to the cold air return (a low tech (and low cost) HRV).  These can be tied to exhaust fans or automatic via pressure differential.  You would want a HVAC firm to discuss options.

A third would be a cable operated chimney cap damper.  The stove may complicate this option.  I had one on a naturally aspirated fireplace and was good during rain and windy conditions that used to produce that "old fire" smell.